# Solubility of Aluminium Hydroxide in Sodium Hydroxide Solution

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility, solutions

Aluminium hydroxide is not soluble in water at all, however I was doing some reading and read that it does in fact dissolve in a solution of sodium hydroxide. This just seemed a bit strange to me, so I was wondering if anyone could explain why this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because $\ce{Al(OH)3}$ is **amphoteric** in nature, it acts as **both acid and base**. When you drop a chunk of $\ce{Al(OH)3}$ into a solution of $\ce{NaOH}$, you would get a soluble salt, which is **sodium aluminate**, and some extra water.

$$\ce{Al(OH)3 + NaOH -> Na[Al(OH)4]}$$

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any way to tell if a substance is amphoteric?

Comment: @Etched Yes, but you need to analyze the structure carefully. In the case of $\ce{Al(OH)3}$, it acts as a base since the $\ce{Al-O}$ bonds are broken, releasing $\ce{OH-}$. But at the same time, it can also accept $\ce{OH-}$ due to the presence of empty electron orbitals that can grasp onto electrons. This is just a little description, if you need more info, please **ask a new question**.

Comment: Another major point is that saying"Aluminium hydroxide is not soluble" isn't entirely correct. When a chemist says "not soluble" what he is really saying is that the solubility is very low. // I'd write the reaction as $$\ce{Al(OH)3 + NaOH -> Na^+[Al(OH)4]^- }$$